# Как писать тесты с помощью Robotium?

Tags: java, android, test-automation

С помощью `Robotium` разработчики могут писать функциональные тесты, охватывающие несколько `Android` активити, долго погуглив ничего толкового не нашел, может кто знает как писать тесты с помощью `Robotium`?

Comment: Посмотрите как начать писать тесты - [Getting Started](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Getting-Started)

Answer (score 0):

Установите Android SDK и Robotium.
Создайте проект тестирования в Eclipse.
Настройте проект тестирования для использования Robotium.
Напишите тесты, используя методы Robotium, такие как solo.clickOnButton(), solo.enterText() и т.д.
Запустите тесты на эмуляторе или устройстве.

Для получения дополнительной информации о Robotium, можете посмотреть официальную документацию.